Firebase Authentication Error: "App not authorized"
I'm encountering an issue with Firebase Authentication in my app where I'm receiving the following error message:

Error: [auth/app-not-authorized] This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [Invalid app info in play_integrity_token]

I've double-checked the package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 fingerprints in the Firebase Console, and they all seem to be correct. Despite this, the error persists.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?
